# Linearly dependent rows and adjoint

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I'm having real trouble understanding this question. I am supposed to figure out if the following statement is true or false, and have been thinking for hours but I cannot seem to think of an answer for this.. Much thanks to anyone who'd be able to explain the following question..!

> If $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix with $2$ linearly dependent rows, then the adjoint of $A$ has at least $n − 2$ zero columns.

Answer (score 0):

The adjoint matrix $\operatorname{adj}A$ has entries
$$
b_{ij}=(-1)^{i+j}\det A_{ji}
$$
where $A_{ji}$ is obtained by removing the $j$-th row and $i$-th column from $A$.

It is not restrictive to assume that the linearly dependent rows of $A$ are the two at the bottom.

Then any determinant that is obtained by removing the $j$-th row where $1\le j\le n-2$ is zero, because the matrix still has two linearly dependent rows. Thus the first $n-2$ columns of $\operatorname{adj}A$ are zero.